# SSD is recognized as HDD in Windows VM in kvm

Tags: virtual-machine, hard-disk, kvm, ssd, storage

im facing with a problem in windows vm,
im using ssd for the vm storage but is shown as HDD type in windows.
is there anyway that i can fix this problem?
i know about lun passthrough, but i dont know how to use it.

My storage XML:

```xml
<disk type="file" device="disk">
 <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
 <source file="/opt/kvm_pool/windows-20220904-154548224932909-110_SSD_Check.qcow2"/>
 <backingStore/>
 <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
 <alias name="virtio-disk0"/>
 <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</disk>
```

Comment: you will need to tell us how you're *currently* running your VM, what tools / QEMU command line / virsh script / libvirt-xml settings are you using?

Comment: im using a simple vm created from Qemu kvm uging virt-manager,and im adding storage to it, everything works just fine, the only thing is that my windows VM cannot recognize SSD and it shows it as a HDD storage in Windows taks manager.

Comment: here is my storage xml : 

<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
  <source file="/opt/kvm_pool/windows-20220904-154548224932909-110_SSD_Check.qcow2"/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
  <alias name="virtio-disk0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</disk>

Comment: oh, that's very helpful! Added it to your question!